# NullPointerException when trying to execute DAO... Could not initialize class ..JavaReflectionManager

Tags: spring-mvc, repository, dao, autowired, hibernate-4.x

I am getting a `NullPointerException` when I try to execute the checkCredentials function in my LoginController. I think the problem is not with my Service Implementation but with DAO Implementation. But I am not able to find what causes the issue. I am not sure if the problem is with the

```
@Autowired
private LoginDAO loginDAO;
```

or the

```
@Repository("loginDAO")
```

When I submit the login credentials I get the following

```
DEBUG - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.accademics.web.controllers.LoginController.checkCredentials(com.accademics.web.models.LoginModel,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)]
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'loginController'
inside controller checkCredentials
LoginModel [username=admin, password=password]
service checking login of admin and password
DEBUG - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.accademics.web.controllers.LoginController.checkCredentials(com.accademics.web.models.LoginModel,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)]: java.lang.NullPointerException
DEBUG - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.accademics.web.controllers.LoginController.checkCredentials(com.accademics.web.models.LoginModel,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)]: java.lang.NullPointerException
DEBUG - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.accademics.web.controllers.LoginController.checkCredentials(com.accademics.web.models.LoginModel,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)]: java.lang.NullPointerException
DEBUG - Could not complete request
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.accademics.data.services.LoginServiceImpl.checkCredentials(LoginServiceImpl.java:18)
    at com.accademics.web.controllers.LoginController.checkCredentials(LoginController.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So here is the root,  applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd">

    <bean id="loginService" class="com.accademics.data.services.LoginServiceImpl"/>

</beans>
```

The dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.accademics.web.controllers"></context:component-scan>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages"></property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>

</beans>
```

student_login.jsp actual content part

```
                        <form  action='<spring:url value="/student/login"></spring:url>' method="post" autocomplete="on"> 
                            <h1>Log in</h1> 
                            <p>
                                <label for></label>
                            </p>
                            <p> 
                                <label for="username" class="uname" > Username </label>
                                <input id="username" name="username" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
                            </p>
                            <p> 
                                <label for="password" class="passwd"> Password </label>
                                <input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder="Password" /> 
                            </p>
                            <p class="keeplogin"> 
                                <input type="checkbox" name="saveLogin" id="saveLogin" value="saveLogin" /> 
                                <label for="saveLogin">Keep me logged in</label>
                            </p>
                            <p class="login button"> 
                                <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
                            </p>
                          </form>
```

LoginController.java

```
package com.accademics.web.controllers;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.accademics.data.services.LoginService;
import com.accademics.web.models.LoginModel;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired 
    public LoginService loginService;

    @Autowired
    MessageSource messagesource;

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayLogin(Model model){
        return "student_login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String checkCredentials(@Valid @ModelAttribute LoginModel loginModel, BindingResult result){     
        System.out.println("inside controller checkCredentials");
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "student_login";
        }
        System.out.println(loginModel);
        boolean userExists = loginService.checkCredentials(loginModel.getUsername(), loginModel.getPassword());
        if(userExists){
            System.out.println("valid");

            return "dashboard";
        }else{
            System.out.println("invalid");
            result.rejectValue("userName", "NotNull.login.invalidUser");
            return "student_login";
        }

    }
}
```

LoginServiceImpl.java

```
package com.accademics.data.services;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.accademics.web.DAO.LoginDAO;

@Service("loginService")
public class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService {

    @Autowired
    private LoginDAO loginDAO;

    @Override
    public boolean checkCredentials(String username, String password) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("service checking login of "+username+" and "+password);
        return loginDAO.checkCredentials(username, password);
    }

}
```

LoginDAO.java

```
package com.accademics.web.DAO;

public interface LoginDAO {

    public boolean checkCredentials(String username, String password);

}
```

LoginDAOImpl.java

```
package com.accademics.web.DAO;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository("loginDAO")
public class LoginDAOImpl implements LoginDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean checkCredentials(String username, String password) {

        System.out.println("Checking login");

        //HQL
        String hquery = "from student_credentials where student_credentials.username=? and student_credentials.password=?";
        boolean userFound = false;
        Session session = getSession();
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery(hquery);
        query.setParameter(0, username);
        query.setParameter(1, password);

        List list = query.list();

        if(!list.isEmpty()){
            userFound = true;
        }

        session.close();
        return userFound;

    }

}
```

and relevant entry in messages.properties

```
NotNull.login.invalidUser = Invalid Username/Password
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

---

I have made the following changes to my dispatcher-servlet and removed the bean tag from applicationContext.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.accademics.web" />



<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>


<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages"></property>
</bean>

<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>
```

which created this new exception.

```
ERROR - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loginController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'loginService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'loginDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loginDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.accademics.web.configuration.HibernateConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'loginDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loginDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.accademics.web.configuration.HibernateConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loginDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.accademics.web.configuration.HibernateConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.accademics.web.configuration.HibernateConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.createReflectionManager(Configuration.java:2547)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.createReflectionManager(Configuration.java:2543)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:293)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.<init>(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:140)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 75 more
```

I really dont understand what is wrong with my code.

---

I now have the solution, which is decribed in the below answer. The second problem was actually related to dependencies.

Comment: Your service bean is part or the root context, where you have not enabled annotations using <context:annotation-config/>, and where you haven't configured component scanning. So the context contains a single bean: the service defined in the xml file.

Comment: @JBNizet I have specified them both in my dispatcher-servlet.xml, which is the front controller. And the service bean get invoked as you can see in my server log. The problem could be with the DAO but I cant understand the issue.

Comment: The dispatcher-servlet.xml defines the child, web context. It scans only the components in com.accademics.web.controllers. So it contains only your controllers from the package, and delegates to the root context to find the other ones. But the root context contains only the service.

Comment: @JBNizet The Service was working fine without the <context:annotation-config/> before adding the DAO with mock data set. Are you saying that DAO required that? I am just a beginner, its difficuilt to understand. Could you please explain more?

Comment: You're explicitly defining the service in your XML configuration. So this service exists, is registered in the spring context, and can thus be injected in the controller. But that's the only bean defined in the root context, since annotation config is not set, component scanning is not configured, and no other bean is defined in the XML.

Comment: @JBNizet Now its returning new exception                                                                                             `org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'loginDAO'; nested exception is org....UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean.. 'loginDAO': Unsatisfied.. through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springfr...NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean... expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

Comment: @JBNizet I have changed component scan in dispatcher servlet to <context:component-scan base-package="com.accademics" />, which caused the new error

Comment: Read the error message. It says: *No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available*. You haven't defined any bean of type Sessionfactory anywhere, but the DAO relies on it. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-hibernate

Comment: @JBNizet Thankyou for being patient and answering my doubts, the problem was actually with my hibernate.properties file. It was a typo when defining driver class. But After correcting it, another exception came up, now being ---> Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.accademics.web.configuration.HibernateConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager

Comment: I have gone through other posts discussing similar issue. There it mentioned that the problem was with the version of hibernate-annotations. But i am using the latest version 3.5.6 with hibernate-4

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the second issue (first which was solved Thanks to @JBNizet)

It was actually regarding the dependencies added in the pom.xml, which I havnt included here. What I did is I actually upgraded my hibernate version to 5.1.0 and then added hibernate-commons-annotations 5.0.1.Final. So my dependencies are now like below.

[image]

The specific, Hibernate core will have hibernate-common-annotation and this has the missing class

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
```

Comment: I am editing my post accordingly so that anyone else having similar issue may find this useful